# Direction of friction in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

I got a question today which was asked

> Find the maximum permissible speed of a car to move in a circle (limiting speed after which car will leave circle) when the friction coefficient between the car and the road is μ.

When I was solving this I got stuck on where would the friction act, in the direction of centripetal or opposite to centripetal. When I solved it I got it wrong.  I also asked from a tutor online and he said it is based on frame of reference you consider.

So I want to get some clarity:  which direction does friction act in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the track is flat the only horizontal force which is present and can produce a centripetal acceleration is friction.
Friction tries to reduce the relative motion between two objects or prevents the relative motion between two objects (the tyres and the ground in this example).
When going around a corner the tenancy for the car due to its inertia is to continue along a straight line and the frictional force is there to overcome that tendency.
So the directional of the frictional force is in the same direction as that of the centripetal acceleration.

*I also asked from a tutor online and he said it is based on frame of reference u take in consideration..*
The frictional force **does not change** direction or magnitude as one moves between reference frames but to be able to use Newton's second law in an accelerated frame (ie the frame of reference in which the car is stationary) an extra (fictitious, pseudo, centrifugal, . . .) force has to be introduced which in this case would be the mass of the car times the centripetal acceleration acting in a direction opposite to that of friction.

Comment: Thanks brother/sister  for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Friction on the tires acts as a centripetal force, the one that makes you perform the circular trajectory.

The second principle of dynamics in the radial direction (positive means pointing towards the center of the circle of curvature) reads

$m \dfrac{v^2}{R} = F^c$

being $m$ the mass of the car, $v$ the magnitude of the velocity, $R$ the radius of curvature of the trajectory, $F^c$ the centripetal force that must be provided by friction that must be

$F^c \le \mu N = \mu m g$

being $N$ the normal reaction equal to the weight of the car $mg$ is the circular trajectory is performed on flat surface (no banked curve).

So, given all the other parameters, the maximum velocity of the car is found using equality

$m \dfrac{v_{max}^2}{R} = \mu m g \qquad \rightarrow \qquad v_{max} = \sqrt{ \mu g R}$

No way it could depend on the reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

Friction always tries to prevent sliding.

So, in circular motion it is pulling inwards towards the centre of the circle so it prevents that the wheels slide out across the asphalt.

Be aware that your question is ill-phrased (possibly hastily translated). $\mu$ is presumably not the friction but rather the friction coefficient, and the static friction limit would be calculated as $f_s=\mu n$.